# is there a better way instead of "Accommodate a method to include an extra thing"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, synonyms

I am writing an Email to a professor and am thinking if there is a better way to deliver this sentence, particularly about the "accommodated the method" part. Is there a better verb instead of "accommodated" to deliver the meaning?

"I appreciate it If you could elaborate how you **accommodated** the LSQR **method** to invert for nonnegative values of C2 Parameter."

Comment: _adapted_ ... or if no adjustment was required, just an extension of the method,  _showed that the LSQR method could be extended, with inversion, for nonnegative values of C2 Parameter_.

Comment: @user405662 Thanks. "Adapted" seems more suitable for what I want.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question was:

> Is there a better way instead of “Accommodate a method to include an extra thing”?

Consider the following two phrases:

- "`better way instead of`"
- "`better way of`"

Those phrases must **ALWAYS** be followed by:

- zero or one adjectives used as an adverb
- exactly one word ending in "`ing`" (a gerund):

For example, we could have:

> - "... a better way instead of **hiking** all of the way back to the car?"
> - "Is there a better way, instead of **destroying** the city?"
> - "Is there a better way of **winning** the race?"
> - "... better way instead of **swimming** ..."
> - "...better way of **looking**-up ..."
> - "...better way of **making** ..."

Your question could be re-worded as:

> Is there a better ***way of writing*** “Accommodate a method to include an extra thing”?
> Is there a better ***way of wording*** “Accommodate a method to include an extra thing”?
> Is there a **better alternative to** “Accommodate a method to include an extra thing”?
> Is there a **better to** say “Accommodate a method to include an extra thing”?

---

You originally wrote,

> "I appreciate it If you could elaborate how you accommodated the LSQR method to invert for nonnegative values of C2 Parameter."

First of all, you are missing some words:

> "I **would** appreciate it if you could elaborate **on** how you accommodated the LSQR method to invert for nonnegative values of **the** C2 Parameter."

Secondly, I am not sure what you mean by "*accommodate*"

"*accommodate*" usually means to do something differently than usual in order to make another person happy.

For example, "At the Barbecue, Bob **accommodated** his vegan cousin by cooking a veggie burger."

You cannot "*accommodate*" the LSQR method, because the LSQR method is not a person.

> "I **would** appreciate it if you could elaborate **on** how you **used** the LSQR method to invert for nonnegative values of **the** C2 Parameter."
>
> ---
>
> "I **would** appreciate it if you could elaborate **on** how you **adjusted** the LSQR method to invert for nonnegative values of **the** C2 Parameter."
>
> ---
>
> "I **would** appreciate it if you could elaborate **on** how you **modified** the LSQR method to invert for nonnegative values of **the** C2 Parameter."
>
> ---
>
> "I **would** appreciate it if you could elaborate **on** how you **employed** the LSQR method to invert for nonnegative values of **the** C2 Parameter."

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. 
Can I rewrite and use "accommodated" in this style? 
 "I would appreciate it if you could elaborate on how you used the LSQR method to accommodate nonnegative values of the C2 Parameter in the inversion process?"

Comment: @Esi Relatively speaking, "`Elaborate on how you used the LSQR method to accommodate nonnegative values`" is better than "`Elaborate on how you accommodated the LSQR method to invert for nonnegative values` However, the word "accommodate" is usually used to refer to people, not methods or numbers. You could also write"`Elaborate on how you used the LSQR method to` ***ACCOUNT FOR*** `nonnegative values`"